# Why are the orbits disjoint?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm reading Beardon's, *Algebra and Geometry*:

> [image]

I'm a bit confused: How can the orbits be pairwise disjoint sets? I understand that the orbits might be disjoint if we're (for example) talking about the trivial permutation:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & 5 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & 5\end{pmatrix}$$

But in general, I understand that some of the orbits might be disjoint while others might not be. The problem for me is that it seems that he worded it like *"they must be"* and I guess that's not generally true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose two orbits $O(k)$ and $O(\ell)$ intersect.  That means there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $\rho^m(k)=\rho^n(\ell)$.  But then notice that $$\rho^s(k)=\rho^{s-m}(\rho^m(k))=\rho^{s-m}(\rho^n(\ell))=\rho^{s-m+n}(\ell)$$ for any integer $s$.  Since $O(k)=\{\rho^s(k):s\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, this shows that $O(k)\subseteq O(\ell)$.  Reversing the roles of $k$ and $\ell$, we get $O(\ell)\subseteq O(k)$ as well, so $O(k)=O(\ell)$.

Comment: I don't understand. Suppose I take $\rho (x)=(1 \quad 3 \quad 5)$. Then the orbit of $1$ is $\{ 3, 5,1\}$, the orbit of $3$ is $\{5,1,3 \}$. How are these disjoint? That is: They must be disjoint coordinate-wise. But it's not so clear that this is what he meant with the writing.

Comment: They are not disjoint; they are equal (the set $\{3,5,1\}$ has the same elements as $\{5,1,3\}$).  The text says any two orbits are either identical or disjoint, not that any two orbits are disjoint.

Comment: @Oppa The objective is to point our that orbits are either completely identical or are completely disjoint. In your example the orbits are completely identical.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Silly me. He said that there are two cases and then investigated what would happen in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

think of actually enacting the permutation on a set of $n$ colored balls arranged in a set of cups numbered $1$ to $n$.

any balls in positions unaffected by the permutation obviously form disjoint orbits of size 1. so we need only consider *derangements* - permutations in which each ball changes position.

take the first ball ($B_1$) in hand, leaving an empty cup. move the ball to its new position, taking in hand the displaced ball ($B_2$). if the permutation calls for this ball into be placed in the empty cup then $B_1$ and $B_2$ form an orbit of size 2. Otherwise place $B_2$ in its new position displacing $B_3$. continue until a ball ($B_k$) is placed in the empty cup. then $B_1, B_2,\dots,B_k$ form an orbit of size $k$.

if any balls remain, repeat the process beginning with ball $B_{k+1}$. it should be clear that all the orbits formed in this way are disjoint.